Why does the rust compiler not allow a + after an if else block to be evaluated?
So I was just playing around with rust expressions and I noticed something weird? When i order the if else block differently it creates different outcomes.
Following snippet is accepted by the compiler:
fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    2 + if  a > b {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}

But following one is rejected with an error:
fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if  a > b {
        a
    } else {
        b
    } + 2  
}

compiler error:
error: leading `+` is not supported
  --> if1.rs:11:7
   |
11 |     } + 2
   |       ^ unexpected `+`
   |
help: parentheses are required to parse this as an expression
   |
7  ~     (if  a > b {
8  |         a
9  |     } else {
10 |         b
11 ~     }) + 2
   |

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> if1.rs:8:9
   |
7  | /     if  a > b {
8  | |         a
   | |         ^ expected `()`, found `i32`
9  | |     } else {
10 | |         b
11 | |     } + 2
   | |_____- expected this to be `()`
   |
help: you might have meant to return this value
   |
8  |         return a;
   |         ++++++  +

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> if1.rs:10:9
   |
7  | /     if  a > b {
8  | |         a
9  | |     } else {
10 | |         b
   | |         ^ expected `()`, found `i32`
11 | |     } + 2
   | |_____- expected this to be `()`
   |
help: you might have meant to return this value
   |
10 |         return b;
   |         ++++++  +

Tried researching and apparently its something to do with how the compiler parses expressions? but I haven't seen any specific information

The problem is that the second form is ambiguous with respect to Rust's grammar. It could be parsed as you are currently expecting it to be, but that would make other corner cases behave poorly. So, instead, it was chosen that this corner case would produce an error. Note that Rust is still capable of parsing it as you would expect it (indeed, it even tell you how to properly write it so that it won't produce an error), but for consistency reasons, Rust will not make an exception out of this particular case and accept it.

This kind of situations are actually very common, in almost every programming language. It is always a matter of trade-off: you trade ambiguity for something else. When this situation arises, in modern languages at least, it often means that the language design team thought that the "something else" was worth more than not having these syntactic oddities.

When a block or control expression is the beginning of a statement, it is parsed as a full statement instead of an expression. See Why does unsafe { x } == y not compile?.

The help message at the first error points directly to the reason and the solution. Please read and consider such diagnostics, they are there for a purpose.
